# My PHP file doesn't open anymore in my browser

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp

I have just started programming with PHP about a week ago and I am making progress. To open my file I have installed XAMPP and I have always been able to open the file until yesterday. I have saved the file in *C:\xampp\htdocs* and I can normally open it by typing *http://localhost/somefile.php* in my browser but it suddenly says that it can not find any website.
Can someone help me?

Comment: `suddenly` it's not a description of what happens. Check if the server is running through xampp.  Or post the exact error you'll obtain or a screenshot

Comment: check that xampp started properly

Comment: Some other program (IIS commonly on windows) or update to Apache change the folder or config file for _http://localhost/_ try with _127.0.0.1_

Comment: Thanks jothi. You solved my problem. Such a stupid mistake. :}

Comment: Try to use usbwebserver:
http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/

Comment: may be the port problem did you installed skype because skype taking port no 80. you know xampp default port no is 80

Comment: To avoid skype issue rather saying port issue, make your xamp run with administrator privileges and use services.msc to start,stop and restart server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your port number

```
This file should be found in C:\xampp\apache\conf on Windows or in bin/apache for Linux.
```

Locate the following lines :

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

Replace them by :

```
Listen 8012
ServerName localhost:8012.
```

Save the file.

Access to : http://localhost:8012/somefile.php for check if it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Check also the port for http, it's usually being used by IIS